# Как удалить одно значение, а не все данные о пользователе?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite3

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start_message(message):
connect = sqlite3.connect('users09870.db')
cursor = connect.cursor()

cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login_id(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        user_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        last_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        city TEXT NOT NULL)""")

connect.commit()

people_id = message.chat.id
user1_name = message.chat.first_name
last_name = message.chat.last_name
username5 = message.chat.username
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT id FROM login_id WHERE id = ?
    UNION
    SELECT user_name FROM login_id WHERE user_name = ?
    UNION
    SELECT last_name FROM login_id WHERE last_name = ? 
    UNION 
    SELECT username FROM login_id WHERE username = ? """,
               (people_id, user1_name, last_name, username5))
data = cursor.fetchone()
if data is None:
    users_id = message.chat.id
    first_name = message.chat.first_name
    last_name1 = message.chat.last_name
    username1 = message.chat.username
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO login_id VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?);",
                   (users_id, f'{first_name}', f'{last_name1}', f'{username1}', ''))
    connect.commit()
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Погода")
    markup.add(btn1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет! Введи свой город, чтобы я мог предоставить тебе погоду.', reply_markup=markup)
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет! Я помню тебя. Если ты хочешь изменить город, введи его заново.')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['unsubscribe'])
def delete(message):
connect = sqlite3.connect('users09870.db')
cursor = connect.cursor()

cursor.execute(f"DELETE FROM login_id WHERE city")
connect.commit()
bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Город удален!')


@bot.message_handler(commands=["add"])
def get_weather(message):
city = message.text.split(' ', 1)[-1].strip().lower()
city1 = city.title()
connect = sqlite3.connect('users09870.db')
cursor = connect.cursor()

cursor.execute(f"UPDATE login_id SET city = '{city}' WHERE id = {message.chat.id}")
connect.commit()

bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Город <b>{city1}</b> записан в базу данных', parse_mode='html')
connect.close()
```

Помогите сделать удаление только одной строки а не всей информации о пользователе,
Есть уже хендлер который сохраняет все данные о пользователи, но когда пользователей хочет поменять город и тут удаляется все данные пользователя и тут путаница пошла, как сделать чтоб удалялось только одна строка? Я вот что-то пытался сделать не получается.

Comment: Перестаньте выделять полужирным шрифтом весь текст. Выделяйте только важные части, на которые следует обратить внимание.

Comment: Чем отличаются колонки `user_name` и `username`? Почему колонки сделаны `UNIQUE` - разве не могут быть одинаковые имена (Вася, Маша) у разных пользователей? Что за название такое для таблицы - `login_id`? Если в ней содержится информация о пользователях, то и назвать её нужно соответствующе, например, `user`.

Comment: Запрос `SELECT ... UNION` - в чём смысл? Вы же уже видели примеры комбинированных условий в `WHERE` - можно использовать `AND` и `OR`. | В запросе с `DELETE` написано `WHERE city` - окончание где? С каким значением сравнивается город?

Comment: Опять в запросе `UPDATE` вы лепите конкатенацию строк: `city = '{city}'`, `id = {message.chat.id}`. Используйте параметры! Знак вопроса `?`, а данные для подстановки в кортеже.

Comment: Колонки user_name (имя пользователя) username (никнейм пользователя). UNIQUE чтобы соединить много SELECT. Ну проект я пока делаю просто для себя, поэтому как я назвал таблицу сейчас, я потом все равно перепишу правильно. Я забыл написать что я начинающий в этом деле и в sqlite3 тоже. Поэтому могу допускать грубые ошибки, но для этого я и здесь чтобы попросить о помощи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оператор `DELETE` удаляет строку, которая удовлетворяет условию, указанному после `WHERE`. Если такогового нет, то будут удалены все записи таблицы.

Если нужно очистить какую-то ячейку, то используйте `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE login_id SET city=null WHERE id=user_id
```

Так вы установите значение столбца city в NULL, в строке, где id равен user_id

В вашем случае запрос будет следующий:

```
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE login_id SET city = null WHERE id = ?", (message.chat.id))
connect.commit()
```

Comment: У меня почему-то не работает, пишет что user_id нет в базе данных. Что нужно подставить вместо id=user_id

Comment: @GuitarBattle user_id был для примера. В запросе необходимо однозначно определить строку, которая будет изменена. Судя по вашему куда, в БД есть некое поле id, я и предположил, что это user_id

Comment: @GuitarBattle я добавил в ответ запрос для вашего кода

Comment: Я дополнил код, просто у меня все равно ошибка пишет. Я вот вроде понял но не совсем.

Comment: cursor.execute(f"UPDATE login_id SET city = null WHERE city = ?", (message.chat.id,)) id заменил на city но все равно не работает

Comment: @GuitarBattle нет, не city, это значение вы убираете и оно не будет однозначно идентифицировать строку. Дополните вопрос ошибкой. По вашему коду, id и есть user_id, users_id = message.chat.id - так вы вносите его в таблицу

Comment: cursor.execute(f"UPDATE login_id SET city = null WHERE id = ?", (message.chat.id,))
sqlite3.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: login_id.city   (вот какая ошибка)

Comment: @GuitarBattle а, ну да, в таблице вы указали - city TEXT NOT NULL. Это поле не может быть пустым. Нельзя просто его очистить. Либо нужно заменить другим городом, либо разрешить null в таблице

Comment: Спасибо, задал параметр что он он может быть пустым теперь все работает.

Comment: @GuitarBattle вам нужно почитать основы sql. У вас очень плохо написаны запросы.